# Setup File or Program Install at user define path while installation

Tags: c#, wix

I'm very new to the WiX toolset. I have to create an installer with 2 requirements:

1. Install the program to the default path. This works well.

The actual thing that i want to know.
2. **User can choose a path. may someone help how to do that setup or program install at user defined path.**

This is the code i have used for default path.

```
<Directory Id="TARGETDIR" Name="SourceDir" />
      <Directory Id="DesktopFolder" Name="Desktop"/>
      <Directory Id="ProgramFilesFolder" />

        <Directory Id="INSTALLDIR" Name="Test" />
          <Directory Id="dirTest" Name="dirTest">

            <Directory Id="ID"  Name="Project Name" />

              <Directory Id="A_ID" Name="NAME" />
                <Directory Id="Queries" Name="Queries" />
                  <Directory Id="v1311" Name="1.3.1.1"/>
```

Answer (score 2):

It's easily found in the documentation

[WixUI_InstallDir Dialog Set](https://wixtoolset.org//documentation/manual/v3/wixui/dialog_reference/wixui_installdir.html)

> WixUI_InstallDir does not allow the user to choose what features to
> install, but it adds a dialog to let the user choose a directory where
> the product will be installed.
>
> This dialog set is defined in the file WixUI_InstallDir.wxs in the
> WixUIExtension in the WiX source code.
>
> **Using WixUI_InstallDir**
>
> To use WixUI_InstallDir, you must set a property named
> WIXUI_INSTALLDIR with a value of the ID of the directory you want the
> user to be able to specify the location of. The directory ID must be
> all uppercase characters because it must be passed from the UI to the
> execute sequence to take effect.

```
<Directory Id="TARGETDIR" Name="SourceDir">
  <Directory Id="ProgramFilesFolder" Name="PFiles">
    <Directory Id="TESTFILEPRODUCTDIR" Name="Test File">
      ...
    </Directory>
   </Directory>
</Directory>
...
<Property Id="WIXUI_INSTALLDIR" Value="TESTFILEPRODUCTDIR" />
<UIRef Id="WixUI_InstallDir" />
```